# alarm is not triggering after 5,6 days

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

I am installing an alarm in my app which triggers every day at defined time and does some execution. My alarm gets trigger fine everyday but after 5 to 6 days it stops triggering. I did not reboot my device. What should be the reason behind it?
here is my manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".Auto_Slot_forwarding.AlarmReceiver" />
```

and the code where i am setting my alarm with specific time everyday

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour());
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());

Intent intent1 = new Intent(AutoForwarding.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
intent1.putExtra("requestCode", code);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AutoForwarding.this, code, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) AutoForwarding.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis()+(days * AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY), days * AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: What device & OS version? Are you aware of https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Comment: using device samsung j7 prime and version 7.0 (Nougat)

Comment: is that due to power saving, the alarms get destroyed? if so then what should be the possible solution to overcome this issue @MorrisonChang